# Why they showed Sanjana as the ultimate choice over all 12 girls?

Tags: ending, whats-your-raashee

In the movie [What's Your Raashee?](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/What%27s_Your_Raashee?), why Sanjana ultimately got married to Yogesh. The whole movie is full of social messages like Child-marriage, dowry, woman exposure etc. Then why did they chose Sanjana over the other 11 girls, Why not choose honest girl like Hansa Parekh?

Comment: Well according to me, among all the girls.. Sanjana was the only one who was normal. By normal I mean she was not representing any social message and was going through simple day to day problems that a normal girl goes through.
Neither she was pampered nor was she too open or too shy.
She was kind of the girl next door.

Plus they both had a lot in common and had build attraction toward each other.
If you Like the comment and satisfies you as an answer please let me know. I'll add it as an answer to this question.....Cheers

Comment: @NishantKumar you can add it as an answer, if you think it is. And i am not fully satisfied with it but still feels its answering it in a way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well according to me, among all the girls, Sanjana was the only one who was normal.

By normal I mean she was not representing any social message, and was going through simple day to day problems that a normal girl goes through. Neither was she pampered nor was she too open or too shy.

She was kind of the girl next door.

Plus they both had a lot in common, and had built up attraction towards each other.

The family also approved of Sanjana during the end.

Finally, the movie was about how people belonging to different sun signs had different personalities and characteristics. Many people believe that some sun signs are more compatible with each other then the rest.

So maybe she was the right girl for him in this respect as well.