# What is the difference between the ending of the novel Kimball Ravenswood and the movie 'What's Your Raashee?'?

Tags: book-adaptation, whats-your-raashee

[What's Your Raashee?](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/What%27s_Your_Raashee%3F) is based on Madhu Rye's novel Kimball Ravenswood. It is said that the film has a different ending than the novel and than the older adaptation [Mr. Yogi (TV series)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mr._Yogi_(TV_series)), too.

I do know the ending of the film and asked [a question on the integrity of it](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/9736/why-they-showed-sanjana-as-the-ultimate-choice-over-all-12-girls). But what is the ending in the novel? Which sunshine girl does he pick to marry? I have read somewhere about the novel having a better ending but can't find what happens in it and what the differences between them are?